# Sqlalchemy - getting data from 4 different tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i am trying to do the following

I have 4 models

```
user            interest         user_interest       offer
-----------     -------------    ------------       ---------
id (pk)         id (pk)          id (pk)            id (pk)
name            name             user_id (fk)       interest_id (fk)
                                 interest_id (fk)
```

A user subscribes to multiple interests. I have to get all offers belonging to the interests subscribed by a particular user.

what are the relations I have to set up. I already have the following relations

for user

```
interests = db.relationship('user_interest', backref='app_user', lazy='dynamic', uselist=True)
```

also do I need `user_interest` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524600/how-do-i-join-three-tables-with-sqlalchemy-and-keeping-all-of-the-columns-in-one

Comment: I did something like this `session.query(offer).filter(<all my conditions>).all()` and it works

Answer (score 0):

you need the following relationships

1.a many to many between user and interest tables

2.a one to many between interest and offer

check out how to make these relationships @ http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html